# Is the unipotent part of the intersection of all Borel subgroups containing a torus connected?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I found this question in Humphreys algebraic groups exercise 26.14

Let $G$ be a connected algebraic group and $T$ a maximal torus.

Is the unipotent part of the intersection of all Borel subgroups containing $T$ connected?

Comment: For a Borel subgroup $B$ containing $T$, there exists an opposite Borel subgroup $B^{-}$ such that $B\cap B^{-}=T$. Thus $\cap_{B:B\supset T}B=T$, whose unipotent part is ${e}$ which is connected.

Comment: Thank you. This is true if $G$ is reductive. But not true for general $G$.